# By the way (can be) = By any chance?

Tags: idioms

According to this [site](https://www.google.com/amp/s/englishtips4u.com/2013/07/21/grammartrivia-by-the-way-vs-by-any-chance/amp/), **by any chance** is usually used in a question, whereas **by the way** is usually used to start a casual conversation, but there's an example shows it can be used in a question. About asking a question, can I interchangeably use either of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two expressions are not related at all, and so not interchangeable.

**"By any chance"** is a set expression that always goes with a polite request.

**"By the way"** is an expression used to change the subject or slightly redirect a conversation. You could do this by making a statement or asking a question, but it's not necessary. There is no special connection between "by the way" and asking questions.